# Linear Algebra: Distinguishing between Vector Subspace and other sets of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Though this is not a specific homework problem, I'm trying to make sure I'm getting (all) the concepts in the section on Vector Spaces and Subspaces (LA, Lay, Sect. 4.1, 4th Ed).

The concept of a vector space seems clear. And the fact that a subspace to a vector space is a specific subset which contains the zero vector and is closed under addition and (scalar) multiplication also seems clear.

By the above, a sub-set of R3 defined by all vectors defined by (a+b, 0, 2a-3b) [where a & b in R] WOULD be a subspace, whereas a sub-set defined by (a+b, -1, 2a-3b) WOULD NOT be a subspace (that is, the second sub-set does NOT include the zero vector).

My trouble is reconciling the wording of "Theorem 1" in that section (all the lower-case "v" variables are vectors): If v1, . . . ,vn are in vector space V, then Span {v1, . . . vn} is a subspace of V.

I'm trying to make sure that I'm right in the following: one could make up a sub-set of vectors drawn from any vector space by any means one wanted; any such set would be just that: a set of vectors with no guarantee of special properties. However, if a set has the additional properties listed above (has zero vector, closed), it is ALSO a sub-SPACE of that vector space (and therefor a vector space in-and-of itself). Is that correct?

And as an aside, the reason a "Span" operation between one (or more) vectors from a vector space will always result in a sub-space (another vector space) is that the definition of a "vector" is the path/line from the origin to the indicated point in some n-space (some RN); thus, when creating a 'Span', by definition each of the vectors is originating from the origin (equivalent to the zero vector), and thus include it in the Span. (And this is why a set which does NOT include the zero vector is not a sub-space, though it may be a sub-set of vectors in the n-space (RN)). Is that also correct?

Thanks for taking the time to answer. (Studying LA and VC on my own, and live in a town with no 4-year college, so no ready access to professorial or grad student help!

Comment: Although it is clear where you are getting confused, can you first carefully define what you think a subspace and the Span of a vector of vectors are? Are you also familiar with what a basis of a vector space is?

Comment: Also, the reason why the zero vector is in every span is because the span of a set is defined as the set of all formal linear combinations of elements in that set, and since you are working over a field with 0, you get the zero vector.

Comment: Subspace: Given vector space V, and H a subset of V, H is a subspace if it meets the three criteria: contains zero vector; closed under vector addition; closed under scalar multiplication.  (My understanding, and paraphrased from the section of LA above-referenced.)

Span (of vectors v1, ... vN): the set of all linear combinations of those vectors (ie: any vector addition or scalar multiplication). (My understanding and also paraphrased from text.)  Thus, the Span of one vector is the line which includes that vector; of two linearly-independent vectors is the plane defined by them; etc.

Comment: Basis of a Vector Space: Don't know. (I glanced ahead, and it will be defined in section 4.3; I'm on 4.1.  Should I just cool my jets (yes, I am pretty old) until I get farther along?)

Thanks, BTW, for helping me clarify this!  Greatly appreciated.